# jquery validation enable form when all fileds valid : do no show error for empty fileds

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want button to enable if all fields are valid, as no button enable and disable works fine, but when I move to next fields it highlights error for all fields, but I do not want this to happend any way to fix it, please guide way for it.

JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('blur', function() {
    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
  $("#myform").validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" class="required" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required email" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" class="required number" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

at the end of input you also have to click outside to form that will blur and will validate . otherwise it won't work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input').on('blur', function() {
        if ($("#myform").valid()) {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);  
        } else {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#myform").validate();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" class="required"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required email"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" class="required number"/><br/>
 

    <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are validating the entire form , this would validate all the fields at the same time. You need to loop through each input and explicitly check each field to see if they are valid. If all of them are valid, only then enable submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('input').on('blur', function() {
     var allowSubmission = true;
     $("input").each(function() {
        if(!$(this).valid()) 
        {
            allowSubmission = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(allowSubmission)
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', false)
    else
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', true)
  });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/sd88wucL/109/

Comment: but that solution will not be easy for form with large no of fileds

Comment: Updated the solution. The key is to validate each field using keyword 'this' when you leave the field

Comment: this works but it highlights error of next input to current one